# Search in table using one or more of 3 parameters laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have search page and there is 3 select lists as input. when user select one or more option and click search button, page will show result that match one or more of this parameters and ignore empty parameters.

I tried to use :

```
if($request->country != null)
{
     $searchResult = DB::table('table_name')->where('country', $request->country);
}

if($request->name != null)
{
     $searchResult = DB::table('table_name')->where('name', $request->name );
}

if($request->city != null)
{
     $searchResult = DB::table('table_name')->where('city', $request->city);
}
```

How i can show results when one or more parameters is empty.
and merge results in one collection.
Or is there any solution better that this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: do u means that u want the 3 parameters effect on same table and get the results?

Comment: yes but some parameters maybe empty or null

Comment: What @mrhn wrote in answer but in your case from question you had just to use chained query builder instead instantiating new results (in second and third condition): `$searchResult->where('name', $request->name)` and `$searchResult->where('city', $request->city)`. Should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use `whereOr()` logic, then its either by country, name or city. This will automatically deal with merging into one collection problem.

```
 $searchResult = DB::table('table_name')->where('country', $request->country)
     ->orWhere('name', $request->name )
     ->orWhere('city', $request->city);
```

To avoid empty parameters, use `when()` function, that only will execute when the condition is true.

```
$searchResult = DB::table('table_name')
    ->when($request->country, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('country', $request->country);
    })->when($request->name, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('name', $request->name);
    })->when($request->city, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->orWhere('city', $request->city);
    });
```

Comment: i got error, syntax error, unexpected '}', Can you check please

Comment: there should be ; on $query->orWhere('city', $request->city)

Comment: I think you should use where not orWhere  as he wants the results that matches all of his search prams combined.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to skip unavailable search parameters you can use.

```
$query=DB::table('table_name');
    switch (true){
        case isset($request->country);
            $query->where('country',$request->country);
            continue;
        case isset($request->city);
            $query->where('city',$request->city);
            continue;
        case isset($request->name);
            $query->where('name',$request->name);
    }
   $result= $query->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed i will try it

Comment: This solution will not be able to search for mulitple fields? and switch cases is kinda to be avoided imo